# extjs tip set closeable

Tags: extjs, tooltip, extjs4.2

I create one instance of Ext.tip.Tip.So when I click on some point then will appears a tip and I'm setting a closable config. But when I click on another field tip doesnt set new closeable value? 
How can I set runtime this value? Here is a part of code:

```
var customTip = new Ext.tip.Tip({
    minWidth: 120,
    listeners: {
        beforehide : function(tip) {
          if (tip.body != null) {
             tip.body.un('mouseenter', window.tipMouseEnter, window);
          }
        }
    }
});
var customTipShowTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask({});
var currentWindow = window;

function showCustomTip(event, html, closable, delayed) {
    if (!(event instanceof Ext.EventObjectImpl)) {
        event = new Ext.EventObjectImpl(event);
    }
    if (delayed == null || delayed) {
        customTipShowTask.delay(500, proceedToShowCustomTip, window, [event, html, closable, delayed]);
        //currentWindow.customTip.update(html);
    } else {
        proceedToShowCustomTip(event, html, closable, delayed);
    }
}

function proceedToShowCustomTip(event, html, closable, delayed) {
    customTipShowTask.cancel();
    currentWindow.customTip.hide();
    currentWindow.customTip.update('');
    if (closable != null) { customTip.closable = closable;
        currentWindow.customTip.closable = closable;
    }
    var xy = getTipXY(event);
    currentWindow.customTip.update(html);
    currentWindow.customTip.showAt(xy);

    if (delayed != null && delayed) {
        currentWindow.customTip.body.on('mouseenter', window.tipMouseEnter, window);
    }
}
```

How to change the closable?

Comment: May I know When are you calling 'showCustomTip' method in your code.

Comment: In some place a calling :

 showCustomTip((evt ? evt : event), html, ns: ns}), false, true);

and another:
showCustomTip((evt ? evt : event), html, ns: ns}), true, true);